# Clipping a figure to content

Tags: graphics

Is it possible to clip a figure inserted with `\includegraphics` to contents? That is, remove all surrounding whitespace.

Comment: Please, do not forget that when you clip/crop a pdf file containing vector-like data, you do not reduce the size of the file. For instance, if you want to zoom into a big image, the big image will be stored in your final file even though a small portion only will be visible. This may also hold true for raster images. If you just want to reduce white space, it is ok.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your figure is in pdf format, use [pdfcrop](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) to automatically crop all whitespace before inserting it.

If it's not in pdf format - you could create a pdf of it before. ;-)

Though there are graphic software tools to crop jpg and png as well. For example, ImageMagick with `convert -trim filename` on the command prompt.

Answer (score 7):

```
\includegraphics[viewport=llx lly urx ury, clip]{file}
\includegraphics[trim=llx lly urx ury, clip]{file}
```

Comment: I know this, but I have to open the file, look for coordinates...

Comment: @Marin: no, with package `overpic`you can get a temporay grid