# Inserting .pdf created in Visio to LaTeX without whitespace

Tags: graphics, pdf, crop, pdfcrop

**Introduction:** I recently created a load of figures in Microsoft Visio. These figures looks great, however, are stored in the .png format. I am interested in raising the picture quality.

**Method:** I am keen to get this to be vector graphics and I thought that the best option would be to save them as .pdf from Visio and load to LaTeX in following manner:

Package (Thanks Sigur):

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Load in LaTeX:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.70]{myFile}\\
\caption{MyCaption}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

**Problem/Question:** My problem is that once I save my file in Visio - it brings a lot of whitespace with it (space under and besides the actual figure). I can't get rid of this whitespace once saving the file to .pdf from visio nor can I rid of this whitespace while including the .pdf in Latex. **What do you think is the best option to get rid of this excess white space?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the "trim" option of `\includegraphics` (part of the `graphicx` package).

Comment: First of all you need `\usepackage{graphicx}` instead of `pdfpages`. After that, you can crop the pdf figure using some options in the command `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @Chris Visio is a vector based program. Visio 2007 and newer can save to pdf directly, this will generate small pdfs with vector content. Still, you have to get rid of the white space. This can be done by changing the paper size in Visio or by using tools like pdfcrop.

Comment: @matth: Thanks for letting me know. Then I confused this software with something else...and since my comment is pointless, I deleted it.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17716/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either adjust the page size in Visio before you export to PDF, or use the Briss application to crop the PDF down to size. I use the same sort of process with diagrams drawn in PowerPoint, and I find that it works ok. You can get Briss from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/).