# How would I trim a bounding box?

Tags: graphics, bounding-box

How do I trim the bounding box of an `.eps` figure?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = 5in]{something.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to trim the top portion so the spacing between the equation and the figure isn't too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `[H]` float placement (supplied by [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)), it isn't actually a float. So you can just use a negative `\vspace` above the image; there is no need to modify float-related spacing, since you're not planning on moving this around.

Alternatively, you can specify a change in the `viewport` of the image. For this, see [Clipping a figure to content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8745/5764).

Comment: How could I trim the float if I switch to `\begin{figure*}`?

Comment: @dustin: It works in exactly the same way. The clipping of the image is independent of the environment.

Comment: @dustin: What documentation?

Comment: @dustin: Use `\includegraphics[trim=0 0 0 50bp,clip]{something.eps}` to remove `50bp` from the top of `something.eps`. The 4 numbers/lengths are `<llx> <lly> <urx> <ury>` and represent the (`x`,`y`) coordinates of the `l`ower-`l`eft and `u`pper-`r`ight corners of the bounding box of the image.