# pstool & psfragfig how to edit the EPS file for moving the placeholder to another position

Tags: positioning, eps, psfrag, epstool

I have generated EPS and TeX files from Matlab. Now I notice if I scale my image the text gets  badly scaled such that my axis names are sitting on my axis even if I reduce the text size to `\scriptsize`.

I would like to move the place holders for the text in the EPS file a little further from the axis. That I tried with Adobe Illustrator but it did not work out. Instead my place holders where not replaced anymore.

Do I have to consider a certain file format or font type?
I am using `pdflatex` and `pstool`.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. Recreate the image so you don't have to scale the content. This would allow you to fine-tune the placement of the replacement text.
2. Use [horizontal spacing techniques](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764) within the replacement text of `\psfrag{<tag>}{<replace>}` to push the content left/right. For example, `\psfrag{xy}{$xy$\hspace{1cm}}` would push the content 5mm to the left (since the default replacement positioning is centered. For consistency, and easy of tweaking, [define a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764) that you can use with specific sets of replacements.

Remember that the full interface provided by [`psfrag`](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) is:

```
\psfrag{<tag>}[<posn>][<psposn>][<scale>][<rot>]{<replacement>}
```

I also suggest playing around with `<posn>` and `<psposn>`:

> **`[<posn>]`**
>
> the LaTeX text reference point. The syntax of this argument is identical to that of the `\makebox` command. Up to two letters may be chosen, one from the list {`t`,`b`,`B`,`c`}, (top, bottom, baseline, center) and another from {`l`,`r`,`c`} (left, right, center). If either letter is omitted, then `c` (center) is assumed. Together, these specify one of 12 anchor points. If the argument is omitted altogether, then `[Bl]`, or
>   left baseline positioning, is assumed—but note that supplying `[]` specifies centered positioning. When running in LaTeX 2.09 compatibility mode, the default alignment is `[bl]`, in order to support legacy documents. Usually this should not make a significant difference.
>
> **`[<psposn>]`**
>
> the PostScript text reference point. The possible arguments are identical to that of `[posn]`, as is the default value, `[Bl]` (`[bl]` in LaTeX 2.09 compatibility mode.)

See the [`psfrag` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/psfrag/pfgguide.pdf) for more detail.

Comment: You solution was the easiest way doing what I asked to do. Thank you for that. But independent of my problem is there a posibility to edit the EPS in Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop to add graphics into the plot which I can not do with Matlab. If so what do I have to consider that pstool still notices the placeholders. Which file format do I have to use or what is the special thing I have to consider when saving the edited EPS file. It did not recognise the placeholders after saving it with Adobe Illustrator. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Nixdae: That would be exactly the thing you need to look out for. From the [`psfrag`](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/psfrag/pfgguide.pdf): "Make sure that your EPS figures contain a simple “tag” word in each position that you would like a
LaTeX replacements. Use a single word, composed of unaccented letters and numbers. Some effort
has been made to allow for more arbitrary tag text, but the mechanism is not infallible; see section
8.1." If the editor (Adobe or otherwise) changes this, `psfrag` will fail.

Comment: Hi Werner,
thanks for your help. How is it about cropping a single image with this solution? Since pdfcrop-options is a package option it is not applicable. Is there any solution I can define the pdfcrop options inside my tex file of the figure. So that I can crop my images individually.
In some cases I want to get rid of my title and just replacing the placeholder without no text does not solve it. I still get same white space above the graphic as before.

Best regards

Comment: @Nixdae: Since you're supposed to use `\includegraphics` with [`psfrag`](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag)-included images, you can use the `bb=<llx> <lly> <urx> <ury>,clip` option to specify a new `b`ounding `b`ox for your image. Here you're updating the `l`ower-`l`eft (`x`,`y`) and `u`pper-`r`ight (`x`,`y`) coordinates. Read about it in the [`graphicx` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) (p 10). Also see [Clipping a figure to content](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8745/5764) where the `viewport` key is used with a similar interface to `bb`.

Comment: For others who want to use Adobe Illustrator for generating or editing the EPS files this link could be helpful.
[getting-illustrator-to-play-nicely-with-psfrag](http://engineeringrevision.com/314/getting-illustrator-to-play-nicely-with-psfrag/)