About \psfrag and [<posn>] and [<psposn>]
I have to confess I have not understood the meaning of [posn] and [psposn] in \psfrag when working on a .eps figure. In the guide, {t,b,B,c} stand for (top, bottom, baseline, center) and {l,r,c} for (left, right, center). But where is the center or the baseline? The center of what?
For example, working with this minimal example:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering

\psfrag{0}{0}
\psfrag{1.5}{1.5}
\psfrag{10}{10}
\psfrag{x}{$X$}
\psfrag{y}{$Y$}

\includegraphics[]{temperature.eps}
\caption{caption}
\label{T* at x*=0}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

I don't really get what I want.

X should be lower, also 10; Y should be more on the left, as 1.5.
Are there other ways to control the position of the replacement? I saw someone using the \hspace{xxcm} and the \vspace for example: \psfrag{x}{\hspace{1cm}$x$}.
Thanks in advence.

You can try it out, as I did with the following example of replacing numbers on the x axis that has a range of 2-10 (eps produced with gnuplot, which introduces a space in the tags before each number for some reason):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\psfrag{ 2}[tr]{2}
\psfrag{ 3}[bc]{3}
\psfrag{ 4}[Bc]{4}
\psfrag{ 5}[cl]{5}
\psfrag{ 6}[cr]{6}
\psfrag{ 7}[bl]{7}
\psfrag{ 8}[tc]{8}
\psfrag{ 9}[bl][tl]{9}
\includegraphics{sinplot.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


From this you can see that the [posn] (i.e., first optional) argument specifies which point of the replacement box is placed at the position of the [psposn] argument, which by default is Bl as mentioned in the manual.
So the top right corner of the 2 is put where the baseline left of the 2 originally was, effectively shifting it down and left. The center right of the 6 is put at the baseline left of the original 6, so that is shifted left and somewhat down. The bottom left of the 7 comes at the baseline left of the original 7, so the vertical position does not change much (compare with 10, which I did not replace) as there is only a small difference between bottom and baseline for all these numbers (note that this would be different for letters with descenders or oldstyle numbers, for example as in the image in the manual showing gA where the g has a descender). The 7 did shift right because of the l specifier.
The second optional argument psposn as mentioned above is the original position to which the new box is aligned. As this is Bl by default you can shift it a little bit further down by specifying bl, a bit more down using cl  or a lot up using tl as in the example for \psfrag{ 9}[bl][tl]{9}, which means 'put the bottom left of the new box where the top left of the old box was'.
If you need more horizontal shift then you can cheat a bit by putting horizontal space in the replacement, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160653/. You can also try to make the replacement font similar in size to the original to reduce the need for repositioning.

Thanks, finally I got it! Then if I enter \psfrag{x}[tc][bc]{x} I get the lowest possible position for the replacement, because I allign the bottom center of the tag to the the top center of the replacement. It is possible to put the replacement a bit lower in case this is not enough? I mean there is the possibility of a further adjustment?

@umby you can use the same trick as in the answer I linked but then for vertical space, i.e., pretend there is something big in the replacement and LaTeX will push the whole box down. The \vphantom command can be used here, that allocates vertical space the size of the argument but doesn't actually print anything. Here something like \psfrag{ 2}[tr]{\vphantom{\huge X}2}.
